# Android TV - No Now Playing notification card

Tags: android

I made TV app using Xamarin / Leanback but app is constantly rejected with No Now playing card notification reason(no further explanation, even when writting appeal to same rejection) , although I tested both in simulator and on real device and playingcard is shown after pressing home button while playing video/audio. So my question is, if someone has more experience in that area how this should be implemented (maybe I got it wrong, but when press home while playing audio/video, audio would still play in background and Now playing notification card is shown on main tv screen), By documentation it says that  when you start to play video/audio you must implement mediasession which I have done, since everything works on my side (even tryed to set higher minimum android version - because dont know which version Android TV used for testing) - I am getting a bit desperate since no further explanation from Android TV team - there is no one else to contact. Also I tryed their TV example in github which has Now playing card implemented only for music part (I have video playing using webview and audio using native player), more over I also dont undestand how this requirement is NOT implemented for example in Netflix Android TV application and it is available in store, if that is REQUIRED then this should be required for ALL?